# jquery mobile date picker displaying twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am currently using Jquery UI datepicker. But the datepicker displays twice(duplicate) on my page. It works fine when i use the datepicker on the first page. 
Below is the example. You can run this example to view the problem.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Datepicker Test</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/experiments/ui-datepicker/jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
   <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First page</h1>
   </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p><a href="#secondPage">Next page with a Datepicker</a></p>    

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Second page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <label for="date">Date Input:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="my_date" value=""  />
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005565/multiple-calendars-displayed-or-value-selected-not-displaying-correctly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947412/datepicker-in-jquery-mobile-is-duplicate-when-is-added-in-a-second-page

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947412/datepicker-in-jquery-mobile-is-duplicate-when-is-added-in-a-second-page

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with your jQuery displaying twice every time you fire it, you can do, `$('.datepicker').hide()` function to automatically hide the datetime picker if you selected a date. Below is a sample code:

```
$(document).on("changeDate", "your input type", function(e)
{
    $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```